# java static methods and calculation with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static

I am trying to calculate and display arrays for my program, but it keeps saying something like you cannot convert a double to a double[], for example, in my code, when I calculate the surface gravity, it says that I cannot like have a mix of an array and a variable, because I declared the universal gravity constant as a variable and everything else in the equation as an array. Another one is when I calculate the radius by dividing the diameter array by 2, and pass the radius variable as an argument in the static method for calculating the surface gravity, the compiler says that a double cannot be converted to a double[] because in the static method for surface gravity, I declared the radius as an array. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class GravityV1{

// calculate surface gravity static method
public static double surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){

    // equation for surface gravity
    double[] g = (G * M) / Math.pow(r, 2);

    // return statement
    return g;
}

// displaying static method
public static void display(String[] planets, double[] radius, double[] 
        mass, double[] g){

    // display output
    System.out.printf("%n", planets, radius, mass, g);
}

// write results to text file static method


public static void main(String args[]){

    // declare array for months
    String[] Planets = new String[8];

    // initialize array
    Planets [0] = "Mercury";
    Planets [1] = "Venus";
    Planets [2] = "Earth";
    Planets [3] = "Mars";
    Planets [4] = "Jupiter";
    Planets [5] = "Saturn";
    Planets [6] = "Uranus";
    Planets [7] = "Neptune";

    // declare array for mass
    double[] mass = new double[8];

    // initialize array
    mass [0] = 3.30E23;
    mass [1] = 4.869E24;
    mass [2] = 5.97E24;
    mass [3] = 6.4219E23;
    mass [4] = 1.900E27;
    mass [5] = 5.68E26;
    mass [6] = 8.683E25;
    mass [7] = 1.0247E26;

    // declare array for diameter
    double[] diameter = new double[8];

    // initialize array
    diameter [0] = 4880;
    diameter [1] = 12103.6;
    diameter [2] = 12756;
    diameter [3] = 6794;
    diameter [4] = 142984;
    diameter [5] = 120536;
    diameter [6] = 51118;
    diameter [7] = 49532;

    // // convert to radius

    // declare radius variable
    double radius;

    // for each loop for displaying
    for(double calc : diameter){

        // calculation for converting to radius
        radius =  calc / 2;
    }

    // // calculate surface gravity

    // declare and initialize universal gravity constant;
    double G = 6.67384 * Math.pow(10, -11);

    // call surface gravity method
    surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calculate the element in double array one-by-one.

Change

```
// calculate surface gravity static method
public static double surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){

    // equation for surface gravity
    double[] g = (G * M) / Math.pow(r, 2);

    // return statement
    return g;
}
```

To

```
// calculate surface gravity static method
public static double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){

    // equation for surface gravity
    double[] g = new double[M.length];

    for(int i=0;i<g.length;i++)
    {
        g[i] = (G * M[i]) / Math.pow(r[i], 2);
    }

    // return statement
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't mix scalars with arrays. You need to rewrite this method:

```
public static double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){

    double[] g = new double[M.length];
    // equation for surface gravity
    for (int i=0; i < g.length; i++) {
        g[i] = (G * M[i]) / Math.pow(r[i], 2);
    }

    // return statement
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completing other answers, you should build up an array of radius (because `surfaceGravity` requires a `double[]` as its 3rd parameter):

```
double[] radius = new double[diameter.length];

// for each loop for displaying
for(int i = 0; i < diameter.length; i++) { 

    // calculation for converting to radius
    radius[i] =  calc / 2;
}
```